# How to loop subset of lists in R?

Tags: r, list, statistics, correlation, pearson

I have a list of 9 lists, see the following code where I want to loop only three lists `p`, `r` and `t` for Pearson, Spearson and Kendall correlations, respectively, instead of all 9 lists. 
The current pseudocode is the following where the test function is `corrplot(M.cor, ...)`, see below the complete pseudocode

```
for (i in p.mat.all) {
...
}
```

Code with `mtcars` test data

```
library("psych")
library("corrplot")   

M <- mtcars 

M.cor <- cor(M)

p.mat.all <- psych::corr.test(M.cor, method = c("pearson", "kendall", "spearman"), 
   adjust = "none", ci = F)

str(p.mat.all)

str(p.mat.all$r)

str(p.mat.all$t)

str(p.mat.all$p)
```

Output about the list of 9 lists

```
List of 9
 $ r     : num [1:11, 1:11] 1 -0.991 -0.993 -0.956 0.939 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:11] "mpg" "cyl" "disp" "hp" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:11] "mpg" "cyl" "disp" "hp" ...
 $ n     : num 11
 $ t     : num [1:11, 1:11] Inf -21.92 -25.4 -9.78 8.22 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:11] "mpg" "cyl" "disp" "hp" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:11] "mpg" "cyl" "disp" "hp" ...
 $ p     : num [1:11, 1:11] 0.00 4.04e-09 1.09e-09 4.32e-06 1.78e-05 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:11] "mpg" "cyl" "disp" "hp" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:11] "mpg" "cyl" "disp" "hp" ...
 $ se    : num [1:11, 1:11] 0 0.0452 0.0391 0.0978 0.1143 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:11] "mpg" "cyl" "disp" "hp" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:11] "mpg" "cyl" "disp" "hp" ...
 $ adjust: chr "none"
 $ sym   : logi TRUE
 $ ci    : NULL
 $ Call  : language psych::corr.test(x = M.cor, method = c("pearson", "kendall", "spearman"),      adjust = "none", ci = F)
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "psych" "corr.test"
 num [1:11, 1:11] 1 -0.991 -0.993 -0.956 0.939 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:11] "mpg" "cyl" "disp" "hp" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:11] "mpg" "cyl" "disp" "hp" ...
 num [1:11, 1:11] Inf -21.92 -25.4 -9.78 8.22 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:11] "mpg" "cyl" "disp" "hp" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:11] "mpg" "cyl" "disp" "hp" ...
 num [1:11, 1:11] 0.00 4.04e-09 1.09e-09 4.32e-06 1.78e-05 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:11] "mpg" "cyl" "disp" "hp" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:11] "mpg" "cyl" "disp" "hp" ...
```

My pseudocode about looping all three correlations with the test function `corrplot`, but it will not work because it goes through all 9 lists

```
for (i in p.mat.all) {
  p.mat <- i
  print("p.mat ===========")
  print(i)    

  alpha <- 0.05 
  corrplot( M.cor,  
          method="color", 
          type="upper", 
          addCoefasPercent = TRUE, 
          tl.col = "black",
          tl.pos = "td", 
          p.mat = p.mat, sig.level = alpha, insig = "blank", 
          order = "original"
  )
}
```

Expected output: loop only `t`, `p` and `r` lists such that they can be passed to the test function `corrplot`

R: 3.3.1
OS: Debian 8.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or with an *apply function:

```
lapply(p.mat.all[c("r","p","t")], function(x) {
  # x takes now first p.mat.all$r, then p.mat.all$p, etc
  print("p.mat ===========")
  print(x)    

  alpha <- 0.05 
  corrplot( M.cor,  
          method="color", 
          type="upper", 
          addCoefasPercent = TRUE, 
          tl.col = "black",
          tl.pos = "td", 
          p.mat = x, sig.level = alpha, insig = "blank", 
          order = "original"
  )
})
```

Comment: Is this equivalent to David's answer? - - Can you please explain your `lapply` function approach little more? - - What is the benefit of it?

Comment: It does yield the same result. The biggest reason to use the apply family is speed and code efficiency. For loops tend to be clunky and lend themselves to coder error. Applies to take a little time to get your head around though, I'm still working on that, but only because I made the mistake of starting with for loops! If you were to make it identical to the plots below add `par(mfrow=c(2,2))` before the apply.

Comment: Yes this is equivalent to @David's answer, but in a more canonical R way. In R we tend to avoid for loops, by using the *apply family of functions (which are still just for loops but in a different syntax). The benefit is more compact code and potential speed ups. In your case there is no speed benefit but in others there will be.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to filter the list before looping, i.e.,

```
for (i in p.mat.all[c("t", "p", "r")]) { 
    ...
}
```

Output for `r` corrplot, `t` corrplot and `p` corrplot

[image]

Comment: Nice graphs, thanks for editing. The processing seems correct. What you see is the three different correlations between each variable. What is exactly your goal that you try to achive?

Comment: Lets move this to a chat?!