# Why white bg with Spearman correlation in corrplot?

Tags: r, lapply, correlation, r-corrplot

The first diagonal background is always white when Spearman cor `r`. 
It never happens with other cor measures.

```
library("psych")
library("corrplot")   

M <- mtcars 
M.cor <- cor(M)

p.mat.all <- psych::corr.test(M.cor, adjust = "none", ci = F)

alpha <- 0.05

col <- colorRampPalette(c("#BB4444", "#EE9988", "#FFFFFF", "#77AADD", "#4477AA"))  

lapply(c("r","p","t"), function(ID) { # http://stackoverflow.com/a/40531043/54964
    x <- p.mat.all[[ID]]    
    corrplot( M.cor, 
              p.mat = x, 
              sig.level = alpha, 
              insig = "blank", 
    ) 
})
```

I put there explicitly `diag = T` but it should be fine without it too.

Fig. 1 Output of minimum example

[image]

No warnings.

R: 3.3.1
OS: Debian 8.5
Ticket for the developer: [#74](https://github.com/taiyun/corrplot/issues/74)

Comment: What did `head(warnings())` say?

Comment: I get `Error in paste(title, " cor ", ID, " significant coefficients marked, p-value < ",  : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'` - maybe I had a copy-paste error?

Comment: @BenBolker Fixed, please see the body.

Comment: @BenBolker I put there now a minimum example of the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the software. It is reported to the developer.

See also the related github issue: https://github.com/taiyun/corrplot/issues/74, shortly referring vsimko:

> This looks like a problem in psych::corr.test and not in corrplot

```
p.mat.all <- psych::corr.test(M.cor, adjust = "none", ci = F)
diag(p.mat.all$r) # produces 1
diag(p.mat.all$p) # produces 0
diag(p.mat.all$t) # produces Inf
```

Workaround

```
par(mfcol = c(1, 3))
M <- cor(mtcars)
p.mat.all <- psych::corr.test(M, adjust = "none", ci = FALSE)

for (ID in c("r", "p", "t")) {
  x <- p.mat.all[[ID]]
  diag(x) <- 0 ### THE WORKAROUND IS HERE ###
  corrplot( M, p.mat = x, sig.level = .05, insig = "blank") 
}
```

Fig. 1 Output

[image]

Comment: @Viliam Simko Can you please explain the workaround a bit?

Comment: ok, since the `psych::corr.test` function produces matrices with different diagonals, I used the `diag(x) <- 0` call to explicitly set the diagonal always to zero. This way, corrplot shows all three diagonals as depicted in the figure above (Fig. 1 Output).